# Does SQL Server 2008 collation matter for storing non-English characters in TFS 2008?

Tags: sql-server, sql

There are compilation issues in our TFS builds since some non-English characters are not recognized. Could this be caused by SQL Server collation? Its been installed as `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS` (not locale-specific).

**Update:** Thanks to both answers for leading me to the right direction. [This article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/qingsongyao/archive/2009/04/10/sql-server-and-utf-8-encoding-1-true-or-false.aspx) also may help other people with the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As db2 stated collation controls sort order not what characters can fit into the column.  As long as the columns are uni-code they will store any value that a computer can generate.

In addition to controlling sort order they also control accent sensitivity for sorting as well as case sensitivity.  In you case the columns are case insensitive and accent sensitive which I would assume are the correct collations for TFS as I believe that it creates the databases for you when you install it for the first time.

Answer (score 1):

I can't say with 100% certainty (there could be some obscure little details of TFS that I'm not familiar with), but I very much doubt it. The collation controls things like sort order, and string equality, and only at the database tier. Any application working with character columns is going to get the same data out of them that it originally put in, regardless of collation.